# How can React add and remove work together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am new to react and am trying to toggle a body class using two different buttons. One is supposed to add a class using an onClick event and the other is supposed to remove the class. Below is an example of my code.

Right now in the console I can see the event fire twice but the class remains. As I stated I am new to React so I know I may be doing this incorrectly.

```
bodyFixed() {
    document.body.classList.add('body-fixed');
}

bodyRelative() {
   document.body.classList.remove('body-fixed');
}
```

Comment: What’s the issue are you facing?

Comment: Please show all your code. It looks to me like your are using react fundamentally wrong, but I can't direct you without seeing how you have this setup

Comment: @Ty Brooks, did you manage to implement it? You can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53508203/4312466), where I provided complete working example and if you have questions - feel free to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to toggle a `className` prop value in the React way.

The React way is having a state prop and having a handler function that will toggle the state value, rather than manipulating the DOM node directly (the way you're doing it).

I would suggest you to take a look at [React Main Concepts: Handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) and later once you feel a little bit more comfortable to read about [Virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html) and [Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) in React.

Here's how can you do it:

```js
const { classNames } = window

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    
    this.state = {
      isToggled: true
    }
    
    this.toggleClass = this.toggleClass.bind(this)
  }
  
  toggleClass() {
    const { isToggled } = this.state
    
    this.setState({
      isToggled: !isToggled
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    const { isToggled } = this.state
    
    const className = classNames({
      'body-fixed': isToggled
    })
  
    return <div className={className}>
      <div>Current `className`: <b>{ className }</b></div>
      <button onClick={this.toggleClass}>Toggle class</button>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/classnames@2.2.6/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I don't really see why you would keep the className in the state, and not as a flag in your state? Why not used the almost default `classnames` package :) Don*t forget to bind the `this.toggleClass` in the constructor, so it doesn't propagate changes throughout it's children (okay, not that relevant here and the dom anyhow changes, still since it's a learner you can learn it correctly to the OP :)

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to modify the dom directly like you would with vanilla js or JQuery, but this is **not** how react is meant to be used. React creates a virtual dom that you create and manage, and then react handle changing the page for you.

I recommend following a guide like [this](https://medium.com/@_erikaybar/one-developers-condensed-intro-to-react-68cbf078f992) one to learn basic setup and concepts (skip to the part where he uses JSX).
I can further point you in the right direction if you show your whole component file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the code I listed earlier. I had my `onClick` events positioned incorrectly. Here is an example of the code I used:

```
bodyFixed() {
  document.body.classList.add('body-fixed');
}  

bodyRelative() {
  document.body.classList.remove('body-fixed');
}


<Toggle>
  {({on, getTogglerProps, setOn, setOff, toggle, showAlert}) =>
  <div>
    <button className="search-icon-top" {...getTogglerProps()}>{on ? <img className="times" onClick={this.bodyRelative} src={require('img/times.svg')} alt=" " /> : <i className="fa fa-search" onClick={this.bodyFixed}></i>}</button>
    <div>
      {on ? <TodaySearchBox /> : ''}
    </div>
  </div>}
</Toggle>
```

This is just a start for now. Thank you for the input.

EDIT: I am open to suggestions. Like I said I am new to React.